# Spring boot application getting shut down in unix environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unix, solaris

I am trying to run Spring Boot application (.jar) in Unix environment. It get shut down in some time. The application has REST webservice and scheduler component. The same jar runs fine in IDE & Windows CMD.

```
2021-01-13 16:46:16.591  INFO 6346 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2021-01-13 16:46:16.592  INFO 6346 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'SFTP service.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2021-01-13 16:46:16.592  INFO 6346 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2021-01-13 16:46:16.598  INFO 6346 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-01-13 16:46:16.601  INFO 6346 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Scheduler code snippet. I am facing reported issue without scheduler code as well.

```
@Component
Public class Task{

@Autowired
Private Environment env;
@Autowired
Private ConnectionFactory conn;

@Scheduled(fixedRate=1500)
public void scheduledRun(){
//monitors map 
}}
```

Adding Logger Configuration

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
<jmxConfigurator/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>

<appender name="SERVICE_DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/service-debug.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>logs/service-debug-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z} [%thread] %X{instructionsId}-%X{fileName} %X{step} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="SERVICE_ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/service-err.log</file>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>logs/service-err-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z} [%thread] %X{instructionsId}-%X{fileName} %X{step} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="trace" level="TRACE"/>
<springProfile name="prod, uat1">
    <logger name="com.service" level="INFO"/>
</springProfile>
<springProfile name="!prod, !uat1">
    <logger name="com.service" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SERVICE_DEBUG" />
    </logger>
</springProfile>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"/>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="SERVICE_DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="SERVICE_ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

POM file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.servicep</groupId>
<artifactId>sftpservice</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>sftp-service</name>
<description>SFTP service</description>

<!-- Properties -->
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!--<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>-->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
</properties>

<!-- Spring Boot Parent to control the version of child dependency-->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <!--<version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>-->
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<!-- Dependencies to build this service - will be imported in project -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring web brings all required dependencies to build web application. i.e. REST Service -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--Dependency for sftp connection-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!--java library to support the SSH protocols on both the client and server side-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
        <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--Unit test dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--API is used to convert JSON to and from POJO (Plain Old Java Object) using property accessor or using annotations-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <!--<version>2.9.8</version>-->
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--logging-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>true</addResources>

            </configuration>
        </plugin> 

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please post your scheduling component's code

Comment: Don't you have more logs, a stack trace? Please share them!

Comment: I couldn't see anything in stack trace apart from given few lines. Even tried to follow thread dump w.r.t PID but cant see anything which leads to termination/shut down.

Comment: *I am trying to run Spring Boot application (.jar) in Unix environment.*  The application should be logging why it's getting shut down.  If it's from someone else, file a bug report.  If it's from your organization, fix it.

Comment: I removed scheduler code and enabled debugger for spring boot application, still it get shut down after some time. I dont see anything more in logs. How to get more logs regarding the shutdown ? Is there any chance it is killed by OS? How to find it ?